# Adding dynamic pages and show in header menu Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have made function which admin can use to add new pages from admin panel which are saved in database. Now I want to show them as menu on the header.

This is my BaseController which load master.blade

```
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if (!is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $pages = Pages::all();
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
}
```

And this is from `master.blade` what I'm trying to show the pages

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to($page->page_id) }}">{{ $page->page_title }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

I get `Undefined variable pages...`

I have tried with simple adding this to `setupLayout()` `$pages = Pages::all();` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass $pages variable to the layout page without which laravel will not identify $pages variable.`View::make($this->layout)->with(["pages"=>$pages])`

Comment: Thank's but still got this `Undefined variable: pages` on the foreach

Comment: You can share variable from construct itself `View::share('pages',$pages);`

Comment: How can i make this?

Comment: `public function __construct(){
 $pages=Pages::all();
 View::share('pages',$pages);
}`
This way all your views get the variable

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the $pages to the view; change this line:

```
$this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
```

To:

```
$this->layout = View::make($this->layout, ['pages' => $pages]);
```

Check the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views), very helpful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank's but still got this `Undefined variable: pages` on the foreach\